# How to add new json node in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here is my current json response.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Yangon","$$hashKey":"object:170"}]
```

But I want to add new node to above json as follow,

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Yangon","$$hashKey":"object:170", "township_id": 1, "township_name": "Ahlone"}]
```

Please help me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @naomik - It's not? (If you assume it's a string, it *is* valid JSON. Though it doesn't really make sense to add properties to JSON: I'd parse it and manipulate the resulting object...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your response into a variable (it probably already is) and just add whatever key/values you want:

**Example**

```
var arr = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Yangon", "$$hashKey": "object:170" }];

arr[0]['township_id'] = 1;
arr[0]['township_name'] = 'Ahlone';
```

**Result**

`[{"id":1,"name":"Yangon","$$hashKey":"object:170","township_id":1,"township_name":"Ahlone"}]`

Answer (score 1):

[`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) is another way of doing this.

```
var arr = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Yangon", "$$hashKey": "object:170" }];
arr[0] = angular.extend(arr[0], {
    "township_id": 1,
    "township_name": "Ahlone"
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the original data exists in an array

Comment: @naomik Sorry about that. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayofobjects=[{"id":1,"name":"Yangon","$$hashKey":"object:170"}]
arrayofbojects[0].township_id: 1;
arrayofbojects[0].township_name: "Ahlone";

console.log(arrayobjectg[0])
```

try this it is tested code.

Comment: This has syntax errors. How and where did you test it ?

Comment: sorry console.log(arrayofobjects[0])